# How do I update rails to 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I update rails to 4.2? 
I   googled it.I have read 3 or 4 so questions about it. But I am confused still. May be because I am new to rails.
Right now I got that the best way is just to specify rails version in my gem file.
Update my rails version

```
jonstark@jonstark-pc:~/rails_projects$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.3
```

And I want to make latest uptodate rails version default

Comment: [This](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) [or this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/415-upgrading-to-rails-4) [or this](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-to-upgrade-to-rails-4-dot-2/)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Rails version. In your case it hasn't changed that much on the app side from 4.0.3 to 4.2.5.1. Nonetheless I would recommend you to run the update script of rails afterwards.

**Important! Don't forget to commit. Before and after.**

**Step 1:**

Update Rails in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.5.1'
```

Run `bundle update`.

**Step 2:**

Run the update script:

```
$ rake rails:update
```

Be careful! It asks you to override a lot of config files. Check the changes and decide if the changes are necessary.

**Step 3:**

Check your Gems if all of them are compatible.

Here also an [Upgrading Guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html) from the Rails Guides.

Answer (score -1):

1. Edit your **Gemfile**, change the existing rails specification:

   `gem 'rails', '~> 4.2', '>= 4.2.5'`
2. Run `bundle update rails`

Comment: This is not sufficient. You'll have to upgrade all your codebase to match the feature exposed by the new version, and fix the various incompatibilities.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti what do you propose then?

Comment: @user2950593 your question is too broad for this format. Depending on the version you are upgrading from (which is not even mentioned in the question), the amount of activities may vary.

Comment: The method to get to rails updated is correct, as a minimum you should review all the changes from where you are starting from to 4.2, upgrading may also introduce other changes to supporting libraries, so you should also check those, so do it in a separate area first..